# Inserting an image into angularjs table with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, image

I have this code below on my website and I want an image to be shown in the rows. I have tried using the  tag in a variable then echoing it, and also directly echoing the  but the image always just shows as text. Is there a way to fix this?

The below snippet shows what I'm trying to achieve with the HTML  tag being echoed in which shows as text when run.

Note: The below snippet breaks because of the PHP as it can't run it so it doesn't really show the issue.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.environment_service_packages = 
    [
      {name: 'Click to expand', info: {text: '<?php
image = "random-image-15.jpg";
$embed = '"<img src=' . '"http://www.spyderonlines.com/image.php?pic=/images/wallpapers/random-image/' . $image . '"' . '>"';

echo "Image:"; echo "$embed";
echo "Above is supposed to look like image at http://www.spyderonlines.com/image.php?pic=/images/wallpapers/random-image/random-image-15.jpg";

?>', show: false}},
      {name: 'obj2', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj2', show:     false}},
    ];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr class="info">
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="x in environment_service_packages">
      <tr ng-click="x.info.show = !x.info.show">
        <td> {{ x.name }}
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="x.info.show">
        <td>
          {{ x.info.text }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: '"<img src=' . '"http... - why do you have 3 quotes starting the string

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky What's wrong with that?

Comment: Why is there php mixed into javascript in the first place? You neeed to use `ng-bind-html` instead of `{{}}` which is only for text

Comment: @charlietfl And how would I do that?

Comment: *"how would I do that"* .... Did you look in the manual?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I have read through http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind-html.asp but I dont understand how I would change the current code to work with `ng-bind-html`

Comment: Should be using official angular docs since w3fools has left out a lot of important information. What is so complicated with changing `{{}}` to `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: @charlietfl Is this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml what your talking about? I am confused by what protractor.js does in the example.

Comment: It is for your tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116976/discussion-between-jez-and-charlietfl).